# Laravel localization. If line(key in array) is missing then add it

Tags: php, laravel, localization, newline

I was looking documentation @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization#overriding-vendor-language-files and found that

> If the specified language line does not exist, the trans function will simply return the language line key. So, using the example above, the trans function would return messages.welcome if the language line does not exist.

So, the language file look's somethink like this

```
return [
'notBlank.price' => 'Price is required',
'notBlank.AreaSelector' => 'Location is required',
];
```

So... now i need to insert language line to this file if it doesn't excists, in bottom case Testing.

```
trans('notBlank.price'); // found and returns Price is required
trans('notBlank.AreaSelector'); // found and returns Location is required
trans('notBlank.Testing'); // not found, so needs to be inserted
```

I do not want to fix it in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Translation\ but on some other level, maybe service provider.

Comment: The link you posted explains this very succinctly `"So, for example, if you need to override..."` What issue are you having?

Comment: Laravel can't write the language file for you dynamically. You have to either update it manually, or use some package that does it for you. I've written my own custom ones for that purpose for some of my customers.

Comment: @JoelHinz Yes, i know that is does't have this functionality, thats why i posted the question. Do you think that service provider is the best method to achieve the wanted functionality ? I tried a lot of examples, and somehow cant manage to work. 

#Steve Do you think that service provider is the best method to achieve the wanted functionality ?

        if (! isset($line)) {
            // here needs to be the functionality to insert it, but i need it outside vendor's. How can i approach this problem ?
            return $key;
        }